# How is information passed between ipconfig and the init process at boot time

Tags: boot, dhcp, init, ip, ipv6

I'm trying to assign an IPv6 address to my machine at early boot time (in order to boot a diskless system over IPv6) with

```
ip -6 addr add $ipv6/108 dev eth0
```

at *nfs-premount*.

This works fine, but as soon as the init process is started, the address I assigned to eth0 is dropped.

How does the init process deal with already configured interfaces? How is the information, gathered by ipconfig at early boot time, passed on to the init process for instance? Does this happen through /run/net-eth0.conf? And if yes can it handle IPv6?

Best

Comment: Ouch, a /108? While technically possible, that is *really* not good common practice. Stick to the default /64 unless you know what you are doing and what will and will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I doubt that this is the issue here, though.

Comment: Agree, it is not the issue here, but it is important :)

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for your network interfaces is in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and IPv6 is fully supported. Here is an example from one of my systems:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xx.yy.zz.222
    netmask 28
    gateway xx.yy.zz.209

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:1::222
    netmask 64
    gateway xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:1::1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of */etc/network/interfaces*. My problem is a bit more complicated though.

I need to assign an IPv6 address at **early boot time**, i.e. in the initramfs phase of the boot process (more specifically at _nfs-premount_). There is no _/etc/network/interfaces_ at this point. This is normally done with _ipconfig_, which, to my knowledge, does **not* support IPv6. Which btw. I find a bit shocking.

Comment: I think ipconfig supports IPv6 just fine, but it is old... These days it is better to use the 'ip' command. Much more flexible.

Comment: Wich is what I do, as mentioned above. My question is: Why is the address I assign to the interface via _ip_ dropped further along in the boot process?

Comment: I think that part goes back to /etc/network/interfaces. What happens when you also add your IPv6 configuration there, using the same settings as you have used earlier in the boot process?